# Mouse Cursor Flickering while peforming DragOver event on Panel control in winform in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, drag-and-drop, panel

I am trying to implement a DRAG DROP event in windows form. The Drag event starts when I select some text in text box, click and hold the right mouse button and start dragging the text from the text box, passes over a panel(Right mouse button still hold/clicked) and then the dragged text has to be dropped over a tree view(release right mouse button).

I want my mouse cursor to change when i am dragging over the panel control. The Cursor do change to my expected cursor icon as of now but it flickers a lot and cursor image is not constant.

I am implementing the logic in Drag Over event handler which i think gets fired again and again automatically while dragging and this results in flickering or some sort of refreshing.

My implementation is as follows:

**ABC.Desginer.cs:**

```
       this.splitterPanel.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.splitterPanel_DragOver);
```

**ABC.cs:**

```
 private void splitterPanel_DragOver(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))               
     {
         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ABC.DefInstance.ImageList1.Images[3]);
         Cursor c = new Cursor(new Bitmap(bmp, 32, 32).GetHicon());

         frmFlat2Obj.DefInstance.splitterPanel.Cursor = c;
         DestroyIcon(c.Handle);
      }
   }
```

My question is: How exactly shall I stop or reduce the mouse cursor flickering while dragging over the Panel??

THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

Comment: Have you tried the `DragEnter` and `DragLeave` events (instead of `DragOver`)?

Comment: `DragOver` is called like mousemove all the time. Do not use it unless you want to give feedback about the spot the mouse is over..

Comment: Hello @Jimi, when i tried with DragEnter event, the cursor din't change to required cursor at all. With DragOver event atleast cursor is changing to required cursor but its flickering between the desired cursor and some other cursor icon which i don't have idea from where it appears.

Comment: That comment was too subtle. You cannot do it this way. You have 2 choices: 1) Use the `GiveFeedback` event of the **source** control to change the Cursors (see the full example in [Control.DoDragDrop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop)) or 2) you have to implement the [IDragSourceHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idragsourcehelper) and [IDropTargetHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idroptargethelper) Shell32 interfaces.

Comment: You can see a full tutorial here: [Shell Style Drag and Drop in .NET (WPF and WinForms)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamroot/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms/) on Microsoft Developer. --- Since you're, appareantly, performing the DragDrop with controls you own, I suggest to use the former method. **BTW**: in the example, as in your code, the Cursors are created on-the-fly. That is possible but it's not a good idea. Create you custom Cursors beforehand (when the Form opens), then dispose of them once when the Form closes.

Comment: Another thing, don't use `[Control].Cursor = [Some Cursor]`, but `Cursor.Current = [Some Cursor]`.

Comment: Hello @Jimi, I implemented GiveFeedback event for my textbox. So now, when i drag the text from textbox then cursor gets changed to desired cursor but only for first time until i perform DragDrop event. Second time onwards when i drag the text then cursor doesn't change to desired cursor and even GiveFeedback, DragEnter event for the textbox are not hit while debugging. Any possible reasons for it?